# My fancybox doesn't work. I followed the tutorial exactly. I am getting images from the surver

Tags: php, html, jquery, fancybox

```
<!-- <head> -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />


        <!-- Header and footer styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainpage.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../AlbumsPage.css">

    <!-- Add jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add fancyBox -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

    <!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel.pack.js"></script>

    <!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script> -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
    </script>
<!-- </head> -->
```

```
<div class="gallery">
<?php 
// Include database configuration file  
// Retrieve images from the database 
$query = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY uploaded_date DESC"); 
    if(!$query) {
        trigger_error("Invalid query: " . $DB->error);
    }
if($query->num_rows > 0){ 
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
        $imageURL = '../phpgallery/'.$row["path"]; 
?>
    <a href="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="<?php echo $row["title"]; ?>" >
        <img src="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" alt="" />
    </a>
<?php } 
} ?>
</div>
</body>
```

[I followed this tutorial](https://www.codexworld.com/create-dynamic-image-gallery-jquery-php-mysql/) but followed fancybox instructions for installation. Instead, it looks like this. [image: Screenshot of page]

I didn't do the thumbnail photo, is that ok?

```
    <a href="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="<?php echo $row["title"]; ?>" >
        <img src="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" alt="" />
    </a>
```

This is mine, and below is the tutorials.

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="big_image_1.jpg"><img src="small_image_1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="big_image_2.jpg"><img src="small_image_2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

I feel like I haven't got my image linking set up correctly, but I can't work out how to. I have adapted my last line of code so it matches the same order and changed `data-fancybox="gallery"` to `class="fancybox" but that didn't change anything.

Is there a way to check that the page is correctly loading in fancybox?

```
This is my file structure
dynamicImageGallery/
├── dbConfig.php
├── index.php
├── fancybox/
│   ├── demo
│   ├── lib
│   └── source
│       ├──jquery.fancybox.css
│       └──jquery.fancybox.pack.js
├── js/
│   └── jquery.min.js
└── mainpage.css
```

edit: Added file structure.

Comment: Open developer tools (Hit F12) and check Console tab for the info. Most likely your file paths are not correct.

Comment: @Janis I have added a file structure. I can't see what is wrong with it but this is what console says: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" for all the scripts I added

Comment: @Janis fixed the issue. Removed the leading `/`

Comment: [https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/)